Need help with determining what is truly a buy transaction
I have been creating a node.js script that watches for buy transactions and I'm having some difficulties. I am fairly new to the Solana RPC API, so some of the data contained within RPC responses such as the Transaction object still doesn't make complete sense to me.
Let's start by listing what I have so far for the script:

I am using a private RPC connection
I get the current slot ID at the start of running the script by calling getSlot
I then use the current slot ID to call getBlocks to get a list of all transactions from the slot ID I currently have up to the current slot
I then iterate through all slots returned and then call getBlock and use the returned block to iterate through all related transaction objects it contains
I am making sure a transaction log doesn't contain the text Error Code: to consider it a successful transaction
I'm also filtering for only transactions that contain the text Instruction: Swap in the logs as well
Then I consider it a buy transaction only if there is a greater than zero difference when comparing both preTokenBalances and postTokenBalances for the token account ID I am running the script for

Now for what I am experiencing when running the script:

I am testing the script using the $WIF account ID: EKpQGSJtjMFqKZ9KQanSqYXRcF8fBopzLHYxdM65zcjm
I am watching the Dexscreener transaction logs for $WIF while testing my output to see how the two compare
The first result I notice is that I am only seeing some of the same buy transactions within my output compared to the Dexscreener transaction logs
The second result I am noticing is that there are buy transaction values that I am logging that are not being logged within the Dexscreener transaction logs
The third result I get is that there are buy transactions the Dexscreener transaction logs are logging that are not showing up in my logs

The only conclusion I can come to at this point is that I am not properly filtering for buy transactions or that I am only filtering for one type of buy transaction. Can someone more familiar with the Transaction object please explain what I am doing wrong when looking specifically for buy transactions and explain how to determine the different types of results for a transaction, such as buy, sell, transfer, etc.?

You need to parse individual DEXs, for example, Raydium and Orca. They all work differently. Therefore, you need to write logic for parsing instructions in the transactions.
Or
You can try Bitquery's DEX APIs on Solana, which provides Buys and sells for tokens.
